# Add a # to beginning of each key in Json Python2.7

Tags: json, python-2.7, rabbitmq

I'm trying to add a "#" at the beginning to each key of a Json object (got it from RabbitMQ api calls)

here is my attempt :

```
#!/bin/python

# Libraries import
import requests
import json
import sys
import os

# Define URLs
overview="/api/overview"
nodes="/api/nodes"
queues="/api/queues"

# Get credentials from file
with open('/credentials') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        user = data['user']
        passwd = data['pass']

# Test which URL we want to call
if ''.join(sys.argv[1]) == "overview":
        commande=overview
if ''.join(sys.argv[1]) == "queues":
   commande=queues
if ''.join(sys.argv[1]) == "nodes":
   commande=nodes

def append(mydict):
        return dict(map(lambda (key, value): ("#"+str(key), value), mydict.items()))

def transform(multileveldict):
        new = append(multileveldict)
        for key, value in new.items():
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                        new[key] = transform(value)
        return new

def upper_keys(x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
                return [upper_keys(v) for v in x]
        elif isinstance(x, dict):
                return dict((k.upper(), upper_keys(v)) for k, v in x.iteritems())
        else:
                return x

# Main
response = requests.get("http://localhost:15672" + commande, auth=(user, passwd))
if(response.ok):
        json_data = json.loads(response.content)
        json = json.dumps(upper_keys(json_data), indent=4)
        print(json)
```

Here is the JSON that I get in "response.content" :

```
[
    {
        "NODE": "rabbit@server567",
        "EXCLUSIVE": false,
        "NAME": "test-01",
        "SYNCHRONISED_SLAVE_NODES": [],
        "SLAVE_NODES": [],
        "AUTO_DELETE": false,
        "VHOST": "/",
        "ARGUMENTS": {},
        "TYPE": "classic",
        "DURABLE": false
    },
    {
        "NODE": "rabbit@server567",
        "EXCLUSIVE": false,
        "NAME": "test-02",
        "SYNCHRONISED_SLAVE_NODES": [],
        "SLAVE_NODES": [],
        "AUTO_DELETE": false,
        "VHOST": "/",
        "ARGUMENTS": {},
        "TYPE": "classic",
        "DURABLE": false
    },
    {
        "NODE": "rabbit@server567",
        "EXCLUSIVE": false,
        "NAME": "test-03",
        "SYNCHRONISED_SLAVE_NODES": [],
        "SLAVE_NODES": [],
        "AUTO_DELETE": false,
        "VHOST": "/",
        "ARGUMENTS": {},
        "TYPE": "classic",
        "DURABLE": false
    },
    {
        "MESSAGES_UNACKNOWLEDGED_RAM": 0,
        "RECOVERABLE_SLAVES": null,
        "CONSUMERS": 0,
        "REDUCTIONS": 9700519,
        "AUTO_DELETE": false,
        "MESSAGE_BYTES_PAGED_OUT": 0,
        "MESSAGE_BYTES_UNACKNOWLEDGED": 0,
        "REDUCTIONS_DETAILS": {
            "RATE": 0.0
        },
        "MESSAGE_BYTES": 0,
        "MESSAGES_UNACKNOWLEDGED": 0,
        "CONSUMER_UTILISATION": null,
        "EXCLUSIVE": false,
        "VHOST": "/",
        "GARBAGE_COLLECTION": {
            "MAX_HEAP_SIZE": 0,
            "MIN_HEAP_SIZE": 233,
            "FULLSWEEP_AFTER": 65535,
            "MINOR_GCS": 15635,
            "MIN_BIN_VHEAP_SIZE": 46422
        },
        "MESSAGES_DETAILS": {
            "RATE": 0.0
        },
        "SLAVE_NODES": [
            "rabbit@server567"
        ],
        "MESSAGE_BYTES_PERSISTENT": 0,
        "POLICY": "ha-all",
        "MESSAGES_PAGED_OUT": 0,
        "NODE": "rabbit@server566",
        "HEAD_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP": null,
        "DURABLE": false,
        "MESSAGES_READY_RAM": 0,
        "STATE": "running",
        "ARGUMENTS": {},
        "EFFECTIVE_POLICY_DEFINITION": {
            "HA-MODE": "all"
        },
        "MESSAGES_READY": 0,
        "MESSAGES_RAM": 0,
        "MESSAGE_BYTES_READY": 0,
        "SINGLE_ACTIVE_CONSUMER_TAG": null,
        "NAME": "test-04",
        "MESSAGES_PERSISTENT": 0,
        "BACKING_QUEUE_STATUS": {
            "MIRROR_SENDERS": 0,
            "Q1": 0,
            "Q3": 0,
            "Q2": 0,
            "Q4": 0,
            "AVG_ACK_EGRESS_RATE": 0.0,
            "MIRROR_SEEN": 0,
            "LEN": 0,
            "TARGET_RAM_COUNT": "infinity",
            "MODE": "default",
            "NEXT_SEQ_ID": 0,
            "DELTA": [
                "delta",
                "undefined",
                0,
                0,
                "undefined"
            ],
            "AVG_ACK_INGRESS_RATE": 0.0,
            "AVG_EGRESS_RATE": 0.0,
            "AVG_INGRESS_RATE": 0.0
        },
        "MESSAGES": 0,
        "IDLE_SINCE": "2020-10-16 13:50:50",
        "OPERATOR_POLICY": null,
        "SYNCHRONISED_SLAVE_NODES": [
            "rabbit@server567"
        ],
        "MEMORY": 10556,
        "EXCLUSIVE_CONSUMER_TAG": null,
        "MESSAGES_READY_DETAILS": {
            "RATE": 0.0
        },
        "TYPE": "classic",
        "MESSAGES_UNACKNOWLEDGED_DETAILS": {
            "RATE": 0.0
        },
        "MESSAGE_BYTES_RAM": 0
    }
]
```

Here, I made every key in uppercase and can display it has JSON but can't find anything to add this "#" to the beginning of each key

PS : I'm new to Python development

Thank you very much

Comment: Obviously, there is no way for us to run that code since we don't know what's running on `http://localhost:15672`. Instead, please show only the relevant code for transforming the JSON (not all that command line parsing), and a (short) example for the JSON itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you have successfully converted every keys in a dictionary into upper case keys, why don't you reuse the method and change the part where you do upper case into prepending "#"

```py
# the one you provided
def upper_keys(x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
                return [upper_keys(v) for v in x]
        elif isinstance(x, dict):
                return dict((k.upper(), upper_keys(v)) for k, v in x.iteritems())
        else:
                return x

# the modified method
def prepend_hash_keys(x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
                return [prepend_hash_keys(v) for v in x]
        elif isinstance(x, dict):
                # this part from k.upper() to "#" + k
                return dict(("#" + k, prepend_hash_keys(v)) for k, v in x.iteritems())
        else:
                return x
```

Comment: Also, `dict.iteritems` is replaced with `dict.items` in [Python 3.0](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3.0#Built-In_Changes). So, I assume author is using Python 2.7

Comment: Perfect, it did the trick, thank you very much
I modified the question to add "Python 2.7" tag

Answer (score 0):

Your `transform` function actually works fine (for Python 2), you just forgot to actually *call* it! Instead, you call *only* `upper_keys`, but not `transform`:

```
json = json.dumps(upper_keys(json_data), indent=4)  # where's transform?
```

If you use both one after the other (order does not matter) it should work:

```
json = {"nested": {"dict": {"with": {"lowercase": "keys"}}}}
print(transform(upper_keys(json)))
# {'#NESTED': {'#DICT': {'#WITH': {'#LOWERCASE': 'keys'}}}}
```

However, both `transform` and `upper_keys` can be simplified a lot using dictionary comprehensions (also available in Python 2), and you can combine both in one function:

```
def transform_upper(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {"#" + k.upper(): transform_upper(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    else:
        return d

print(transform_upper(json))
# {'#NESTED': {'#DICT': {'#WITH': {'#LOWERCASE': 'keys'}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it you already tried something like that in append() function.
If you modify that a bit to have something like this, it may do what you are looking for:

```
mydict = {
  'name':1,
  'surname':2
}

def append(mydict):
  new_dict = {}
  for key, val in mydict.items():
    new_dict['#'+key]=val
  return new_dict

print(append(mydict))
```